# Cannot find a search term to Split a Longint

Tags: delphi, long-integer

I don't know the words to use for a search.

I have a four-byte LongInt and I need to get the value of the first two bytes as an Integer and the same for the last two bytes as another integer.

Having an old fart's memory moment here. :)

I guess it is something to do with the Least-Significant and Most-Significant but a good search term is alluding me.

Comment: Low and high word typically is what is used, AFAIK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
uses Winapi.Windows;

var
    L : longint;  // DWORD
    lsw : word;
    msw : word;

begin
   lsw := LoWord(L);
   msw := HiWord(L);
end;
```

Comment: Arrrghhh, slapping forehead. Thanks Dave.

Answer (score 6):

There are many different ways to tackle this:

```
uses
  Windows;

var
  Value : Longint;
  l : Word;
  h : Word;
begin
  Value := ...;
  l := LOWORD(Value);
  h := HIWORD(Value);
end;
```

```
uses
  SysUtils;

var
  Value : Longint;
  l : Word;
  h : Word;
begin
  Value := ...;
  l := LongRec(Value).Lo;
  h := LongRec(Value).Hi;
end;
```

```
var
  Value : Longint;
  l : Word;
  h : Word;
begin
  Value := ...;
  l := Word(Value);
  h := Word(Value shr 16);
end;
```